# Solving recursive relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to solve the following recursive relation
$$K_{2i-2}=\frac{a+K_{2i}}{1+aK_{2i}}\quad;\quad K_{2N}=0$$
and $i=1,\cdots,N$

I want to find the solution for $K_{2i}$.

---

I believe that this relation has to solved from top to bottom. My attempt was to first put $i=N$ that gives
$$K_{2N-2}=a$$
then $i=N-1$ gives
$$K_{2N-4}=\frac{2a}{1+a^2}$$
then $i=N-2$ gives
$$K_{2N-6}=\frac{a+\frac{2a}{1+a^2}}{1+\frac{2a^2}{1+a^2}}=\frac{a^3+3a}{1+3a^2}$$
then $i=N-3$ gives
$$K_{2N-8}=\frac{4a^3+4a}{1+6a^2+a^4}$$
then $i=N-4$ gives
$$K_{2N-10}=\frac{a^5+10a^3+5a}{1+10a^2+5a^4}$$

I can't find any pattern in it. How can I solve it?

Comment: Why do you want a closed formula?

Comment: @lhf actually I am trying to prove an identity which says that if $a=\frac{q^2-p^2}{q^2+p^2}$ then $K_{2i}=\frac{q^{2(N-i)}-p^{2(N-i)}}{q^{2(N-i)}+p^{2(N-i)}}$. I tired to simply the problem to ask here.

Comment: __Hint:__ The coefficients are binomial coefficients. It should remind you of the tangent multi angle formula, so that's one place to start.

Comment: Also, if your goal is to prove the identify in the comment, just do it directly. Can you show what you're tried and where you're stuck?

Comment: @CalvinLin my goal is actually to prove the identity in my above comment. I was trying to first solve for $K_{2i-2}$ for $i=N,N-1,\cdots$ series and was hoping that I would be able to find a series that would imitate my required solution.

Comment: As I said, "to prove the identify in the comment, just do it directly". It's a simple induction step, you just have to check your arithmetic. So, "Can you show what you're tried and where you're stuck?"?

Comment: @CalvinLin I am stuck at this point $K_{2i}=\frac{\frac{q^{2}-p^{2}}{q^{2}+p^{2}}+K_{2i+2}}{1+\frac{q^{2}-p^{2}}{q^{2}+p^{2}}K_{2i+2}} =\frac{\frac{q^{2}-p^{2}}{q^{2}+p^{2}}+\frac{p^2-q^2+(p^2+q^2)K_{2i+4}}{p^2+q^2+(p^2-q^2)K_{2i+4}}}{1+\frac{q^{2}-p^{2}}{q^{2}+p^{2}}\frac{p^2-q^2+(p^2+q^2)K_{2i+4}}{p^2+q^2+(p^2-q^2)K_{2i+4}}}$ and as I put more and more terms for $K_{x}$ the expression become more and more difficult to handle.

Comment: The point is to prove by induction (Not to prove by recursively replacing the terms, which is what you're doing) IE, by the induction hypothesis, what is $K_{2i+2}$? substitute that into the formula and simplify it, which it should work out if your equation is correct. (Side note:  Maybe you're confused that "we can only induct upwards on $i$. If so, define $L_i = K_{2N-2i}$ and show a similar formula for $L_i$)

Answer (score 0):

Claim: $$K_{2N-2n} = \frac { \sum_i {n\choose 2i+1} a^{2i+1} } {\sum_i {n\choose 2i} a^{2i}}$$

This is easily proved by induction on $n$.